# Continuous speech recognition in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

When I start my activity or fragment I want to start speech recognize and when user speak and if it match to some string then result will be display. After result it should again start to recognize

Here, is the code which I tried. It's start on press of one button and when user didn't speak it generate error and after that it's not recognize any thing until I start again by pressing button.

I know above is default case for speech recognize but How Can I do continuously?

> activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/speak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mSpeechRecognizer: SpeechRecognizer
    private lateinit var mSpeechRecognizerIntent: Intent
    private var mIslistening = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        speak.setOnClickListener {
            mIslistening = true;
            mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening()
            val listener: SpeechRecognitionListener = SpeechRecognitionListener()
            mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener)
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent)

        }
        speechToText()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (mSpeechRecognizer != null) {
            mSpeechRecognizer.destroy()
        }
    }

    private fun speechToText() {
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this)
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
        )
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.packageName)

    }


    inner class SpeechRecognitionListener() : RecognitionListener {

        override fun onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        }

        override fun onBufferReceived(buffer: ByteArray) {}
        override fun onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.e("TAG", "onEndOfSpeech");
        }

        override fun onError(error: Int) {

            Log.d("TAG", "error = $error");
        }

        override fun onEvent(eventType: Int, params: Bundle) {}
        override fun onPartialResults(partialResults: Bundle) {}
        override fun onReadyForSpeech(params: Bundle) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onReadyForSpeech") //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        override fun onResults(results: Bundle) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "onResults"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            val matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)
            matches?.let {
                if (matches.isNotEmpty()) {
                    text.text = matches[0].toString()
                    Log.e("Test", matches[0].toString());
                }
            }

            // matches are the return values of speech recognition engine
            // Use these values for whatever you wish to do
        }

        override fun onRmsChanged(rmsdB: Float) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with this : You have to again startListening your intent once your result is a success.
write this `mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent)` in your `onResults` method.

Comment: in sort you have to do button.performClick() after getting result in your `onResult()` method. Might be its work

Comment: it's not case. Not every time you got result. When listener start and no one answer than it's generate onError and we can't start listener in onError because I tried that in it's going in loop. I did some solution but that not correct way so finding correct solution.